# Rounding number by .5 into 1 decimal place in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a JavaScript program where in the average of rating of numbers must be round off by `point 5` (e.g. `4.5, 3.5, 3.0, 4.0, 2.5, 2.0`) no in between numbers such as `4.2 or 3.3` or something.

Here's my code:

```
let rating = [5, 3, 4, 5];
rating.reduce((acc, num) => num + acc, 0)/ rating.length
```

This by default will output `4.25` instead of `4.5`. If the rating is `let rating = [5, 5, 4, 5];` it will output `4.75`. I need to fix my JS to round off or atleast display the average rounding off by `.5`.

Any idea what should I fix on my program to attain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by 2, round, then divide by 2:

```js
const rating = [5, 3, 4, 5];
const avg = rating.reduce((acc, num) => num + acc, 0)/ rating.length
const roundedAvg = Math.round(avg * 2) / 2;
console.log(roundedAvg);
```

If you want the trailing 0, use `toFixed` to get a string after rounding:

```js
const rating = [5, 3, 4, 5];
const avg = rating.reduce((acc, num) => num + acc, 0)/ rating.length
const roundedAvg = Math.round(avg * 2) / 2;
console.log(roundedAvg.toFixed(1));
```

Comment: This looks good however if the value are `const rating = [3, 3];` it will only output 3 instead of `3.0` how work around on this?